Why do ZMQ PUSH/PULL and PUB/SUB patterns behave differently for late joiners?
I'm observing different behaviors between ZMQ PUSH/PULL and PUB/SUB patterns when using ZMQStream. In PUSH/PULL, if my PULL socket starts late, it still receives messages that were sent earlier. However, in PUB/SUB, if the subscriber starts late, it misses all messages sent before it connected.
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop, zmqstream
import zmq
import time

# PUSH/PULL Example
def push_example():
    context = zmq.Context()
    push_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
    push_stream = zmqstream.ZMQStream(push_socket)
    push_socket.connect("tcp://*:5555")
    
    # Messages get queued even if PULL isn't started yet
    push_stream.send_string("Message 1")  # This will be received when PULL starts
    
def pull_example():
    context = zmq.Context()
    pull_socket = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
    pull_stream = zmqstream.ZMQStream(pull_socket)
    pull_socket.bind("tcp://localhost:5555")
    # Will receive Message 1 even though started late

# PUB/SUB Example
def pub_example():
    context = zmq.Context()
    pub_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    pub_stream = zmqstream.ZMQStream(pub_socket)
    pub_socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")
    
    # Message will be lost if SUB isn't already listening
    pub_stream.send_string("Message 1")  # This will be missed by late subscriber
    
def sub_example():
    context = zmq.Context()
    sub_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    sub_stream = zmqstream.ZMQStream(sub_socket)
    sub_socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5555")
    sub_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")
    # Will NOT receive Message 1 since started late


From what I understand, this basically comes down to these socket types having different semantics. PUB/SUB is okay with losing messages, a PUB socket will not queue messages when there are no SUB sockets listening.
